# Bourbon Bitters error after installation

Tags: ruby, angularjs, rubygems, bourbon

I would give a try to bourbon sass framework, so I start installing it.

As I want to use it along with yeoman/angular-generator I had to downgrade Bourbon to v3.2.1 and Neat to v1.5 to avoid compiling error.

After downgrading no problem, they are working fine.

Now I would like to add Bitters, so, following the docs I run:

```
$ sudo gem install bitters
```

as output I got as expected

```
Successfully installed bitters-0.10.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bitters-0.10.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for bitters-0.10.0...
```

then I moved to sass folder and when I try to run:

```
$ bitters install
```

I get this error output:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bitters-0.10.0/lib/bitters/generator.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
method_options path: :string
                    ^
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bitters-0.10.0/bin/../lib/bitters.rb:2
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bitters-0.10.0/bin/bitters:3
from /usr/bin/bitters:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bitters:19
```

I get the same running `bitters -v`

Any Idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that is possible to simply clone the scss file from https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters, also if I think this is not the most elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use old `Ruby` version `1.8` but gem `bitters` need version after `1.9` this indicate `path: :string` new hash syntax instead old rocket hash `:path => :string`. Update `Ruby` to >= `1.9`.

And look in `bitters` gem requirements:

> Ruby 1.9.3+